# What ingredients are used to make a bitter drink will poison vampires when they drink your blood?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Does anyone know what ingredients to use to make a bitter drink that will poison vampires when they try to drink your blood. I'm also hoping this will also prevent you from turning into one.

Can this be found by playing an earlier version of Elder Scrolls?

I got this from a book I found and read, "DE RERUM DIRENNIS" by Vorian Direnni. In it the writer mentions that Asliel Direnni, his ancestor, once made a bitter tasting drink and gave it to a girl, whom a vampire was feasting on at night. It poisoned her blood for the vampire, but left her unharmed. When the vampire drank her blood, he was found as dust the next morning.

The book does not say if it paralyzed him, causing him to burn up in the daylight, or if it turned him to dust

Comment: @desaivv, not all books. After reading Wabbajack book, because of it I refuse to read any books that are not part of a quest. Or have an obvious title, like, the red eagle sword book. I literally use the term "wabbajack" when I'm going stur-crazy at work now.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no such thing from the game (I also don't remember any such thing in TES2, 3, and 4).  Vampires don't really feast on you in Skyrim, they have a spell that absorbs your life (doesn't even require direct contact).  Its this spell that can cause you to contract the disease.

There are also various enchanted equipment and/or potions that can resist or cure disease in the various games, but none of these will kill a vampire that's 'feeding' on you.

Comment: It's hard to know what potion combinations will do what. I honestly think if they mention it in a book, then its possible to make it.

Comment: @b01 actually every possible potion combination in all the TES games are well known since the construction set for them are all out (other than Skyrim).  And all the ingredient combinations for every alchemy ingredient has been found already.

Answer (score 0):

I too am not aware that this kind of potion exists within the game. But if you are afraid of becoming a vampire, there are two ways to "immunize" yourself through easy preventive actions.

1) Always carry some "Cure Disease" Potions in your pocket (you can mix them yourself or buy it from an alchemist), and after you cleared out a vampire's den (or came across one in the field) check yourself if you have caught something. Open your spellbook, scroll down to "Active Effects" and check if there is a "Sanguinare Vampiris" in red letters. If there is, drink a "Cure disease" potion, which will get rid of it. Thats how I do it.

2) Within the game there are items enchantet with +disease resistance. What I have seen, they can be found in the world or bought from vendors. You can also disenchant them and put an +disease resistance enchant on a ring/necklace of your own. As soon as the +disease resistance on your gear adds up to 100%, you will be totally immune to any kind of disease in the game.

I prefer to put more useful enchantments on my gear, so I simply carry some "Cure disease" potions in my bags and check myself after each vampire encounter. Hope that helped,
FRU33

Comment: You also forgot about doing the Companions questline, since events can transpire that will render you immune to diseases.